# Printing pointer raises a runtime error

Tags: c, pointers

I am studying C at school , and I am facing a problem with pointers , Why does this unhandled error rise (im using visual studio 2013 express for desktop on 64 bit windows 10) , when I try to run the code below.

My question is , Why is this happening?

***Code Block :***

```
// ~~ Libraries Or Header Files. ~~ //

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ~~ Main Function ~~ //
int main(void)
{
    // ~ Variables ~ //
    int  * p = NULL;//#define NULL ((void *)0)
    printf(*p);
  //printf(p)l also raises an error.



    // ~ END ~ //
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

***Error**:*

> *" Unhandled exception at 0x009A3C2A in hwQ3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation 
>   reading location 0x00000000 ".*

Comment: who told you to deference a NULL pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this code.

First, `printf` expects its first argument to be a *format string*, and the type of the argument is assumed to be `const char *` (it's a pointer to the first character in a zero-terminated string).  Since the object `p` has type `int *`, the *expression* `*p` has type `int`, so it's the wrong type, and the *value* of `*p` isn't a valid address of a string, because...

You've initialized `p` to `NULL`.  `NULL` is an *invalid* pointer value that's guaranteed to compare unequal to any valid pointer value (it's a well-defined "nowhere" value).  When you write `*p`, you're saying, "I want the value of the integer object `p` points to."  Since `p` points "nowhere", the behavior of the operation is *undefined*, and one possible result of undefined behavior is a segfault.

So...

If you want to print the value of the integer object that `p` points to, you would write something like

```
printf( "%d\n", *p );
```

but *only* after you do a sanity check on `p` to make sure it isn't `NULL`:

```
if ( p ) // or p != NULL
  printf( "%d\n", *p );
```

*Valid* pointer values are obtained by one of the following methods:

- Using the unary `&` operator on an *lvalue* (an expression that refers to an object in memory such that the object may be read or updated):

  ```
      p = &x;       // x is an integer object
      p = &a[i];    // a is an array of integer, so a[i] is an integer object
      p = &foo.bar; // foo is a struct with an int member named bar, so foo.bar is an integer object
  ```

  etc.

  Calling one of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`:

  ```
      p = malloc( sizeof *p );
  ```

  Using an array expression in most circumstances.  Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to intialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  In the case of `printf`, when we write

  ```
      printf( "this is a test\n" );
  ```

  the type of the string literal `"this is a test\n"` is converted from type "16-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and its value is the address of the first character in the string - that address value is what actually gets passed to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to printf(...) is a const char *format so in both cases you're trying to dereference a NULL pointer.  That causes you to access memory outside your allowable range (at zero).

Answer (score 0):

**Basic information about pointers:**

Pointers are to declare a pointer variable, set it to point somewhere, and finally manipulate the value that it points to. A simple pointer declaration looks like this:

```
int *ip;
```

Pointers are generated with the `address-of'' operator &, which we can also think of as the`pointer-to'' operator. Demonstrating this by declaring (and initializing) an int variable i, and then setting ip to point to it:

```
int i = 5;
ip = &i;
```

**Example pointer usage:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int var =10;
    int *ptr = &var;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

*What happens when you deference the pointer to NULL?*

```
int *a = NULL;  // a is a null pointer
int b = *a;     // CRASH: dereferencing a, trying to read it
*a = 0;         // CRASH: dereferencing b, trying to write it
```

Comment: Would also be helpful to understand 'what the pointer stores' (an address)... use `%p` for printing a pointer... `printf("%p\n", ptr);`

Comment: printf("%p\n", ptr); will point to the address which pointer refers, it shows 0x7ffc5625641c in my 64bit machine. Formate specifier %p : print pointer address stored in pointer

Comment: Correct. `0x7ffc5625641c` is the address of your `var` pointer.